# Get mercurial repository info via URL using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mercurial

I`m developing desktop application that pulls repository information (commits, lines of code changed..). Then it should group that info further to show progress for each author.

I have founded .Net library http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/, but to work with it (even initialize Repository object) I need to set repository path, stored on local machine:

```
public Repository(string rootPath) {...} - method from library
```

Is it possible to get repository info without cloning repository?
Are there any libraries that will help me?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mercurial does not have any data sent over the network that gives you access to history or things like that except for the data related to pushing, pulling, or checking incoming/outgoing (pretty much the same thing).

There are ways to host a Mercurial repository though using a web server, but this requires that the server is doing that. In this case you could scrape the webpages for information. You could of course create your own hosting solution that would be able to retrieve logs and files and such through a web service, but there's nothing built into Mercurial for this.

You can identify the topmost changeset and some basic information over the network using `hg identify`, but other than that you need to pull to a local repository before being able to access logs and files and whatnot.

This is a limitation inherent in Mercurial and not in any library.